# What happens when Shen ults Vladimir about to use sanguine pool?

Tags: league-of-legends

Every time Shen uses Stand United on an ally there will be a purple shield surrounding the allied champion's body while Shen channels a teleport to the ally's location.

If Vladimir uses Sanguine Pool during this channel, will the shield show any change in animation? Or is Vladimir unable to use the ability? Will it break the channel?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question follows the FAQ (or, if there's a point to the question at all).

Comment: leaning towards my ultimate question being 'will the pool break the channel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Sanguine Pool will have no effect on Shen's ult.

Shen will appear as expected, and Vlad will get the shield, as expected (though due to his un-targetability, he won't be able to use it until Sanguine Pool finishes).

Comment: How will that appear graphically ?

Comment: Shen's ult centered above Vlad's pool.